# Find longest subsequnce- cant reset the array

Tags: javascript

I have a solution:

theres a task to find a longest common subsequence

```
function LCS(x, y) {
  let res = [];
  let temp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let val1 = x[i];
    console.log("val 1 is " + val1);
    for (let j = i; j < y.length; j++) {
      let val2 = y[j];
      console.log("val 2 is " + val2);
      if (val1 == val2) {
        console.log("they are the same");
        temp.push(val1);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (temp.length > res.length) {
      res = [...temp]; 
    }
  }
  return res.join("");
}
```

and for:

```
console.log(LCS("abxabc", "abyabc"))
```

the return value is:

```
ababc  instead of  `abc`
```

I think the logic is right, but i dont know why the 'ab' is not resseted. How to fix this? I think i only need this minor fix and the function will be completed. I want to undestand the task, not copy-paste the solution. I tried moving

```
temp = []
```

to outer loop but it didnt work.

Comment: Your logic is wrong, but "ababc" is the longest common subsequence in your example. Are you sure you're actually looking for subsequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move `temp` into the outer loop. So you don't need to reset it (that was your right intention).
2. Fill `temp` in the inner loop while the chars from both the loops match.
3. Not obligatory - you don't need `[...temp]` - just assign directly.

```js
function LCS(x, y) {
  let res = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let temp = [];
    for (let j = i; j < y.length; j++) {
      let val1 = x[j];
      let val2 = y[j];
      if (val1 == val2) {
        temp.push(val1);
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
    if (temp.length > res.length) {
      res = temp;
    }
  }
  return res.join("");
}

console.log(LCS("abxabc", "abyabc"))
```

Btw there's no need in the `temp` array, just operate on indices:

```js
function LCS(x, y) {
  let start = 0, len = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0, j; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < y.length && x[j] === y[j]; j++) {}
    if (j - i > len) {
      start = i, len = j - i;
    }
  }
  return x.slice(start, start + len);
}

console.log(LCS("abxabc", "abyabc"))
```

It's also much faster:

```
` Chrome/122
-------------------------------------------------
indices     1.00x | x10000000 248 250 255 257 257
temp array  4.35x |  x1000000 108 109 111 112 115
-------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
function LCS(x, y) {
  let res = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let temp = [];
    for (let j = i; j < y.length; j++) {
      let val1 = x[j];
      let val2 = y[j];
      if (val1 == val2) {
        temp.push(val1);
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
    if (temp.length > res.length) {
      res = temp;
    }
  }
  return res.join("");
}

function LCS2(x, y) {
  let start = 0, len = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0, j; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < y.length && x[j] === y[j]; j++) {}
    if (j - i > len) {
      start = i, len = j - i;
    }
  }
  return x.slice(start, start + len);
}
// @benchmark temp array
LCS("abxabc", "abyabc")
// @benchmark indices
LCS2("abxabc", "abyabc")

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));
```